# Unable to call a class in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
try{

    $test = new TestAccessModifiers("2345","xyz","vfd","a0001","99","67"); /*invoking the class*/

    var_dump($test->calculate());
}
catch(Exception $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>

<?php 
class TestAccessModifiers {


    function TestAccessModifiers($user_p,$user_fn,$user_ln,$user_id,$marks1,$marks2) {
        echo "hello1";
        $this->user_phone=$user_p;
        $this->user_fname=$user_fn;
        $this->user_lname=$user_ln;
        $this->user_id=$user_id;
        $this->marks1=$marks1;
        $this->marks2=$marks2;


        echo $this->marks1;
    }
    private  $additional_marks = 10;
    public static function calculate(){


        return $this->marks1+$this->marks2+$this->getAdditionalmarks();

    }

    public function getAdditionalmarks(){

        return $this->additional_marks;
    }


}
?>
```

Above is the simple code i am trying to run... but i am unable to call TestAccessModifiers 
I have tried using _constructor too

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar This appears to be his output http://codepad.org/C4r2605E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling the class in another php page, make sure you include it like this.

```
include('/path/to/your/class.php');
$test = new TestAccessModifiers("2345", "xyz", "vfd", "a0001", "99", "67");
```

or if you are instantiating the object within the same file then place the instantiation code below your class.

```
class TestAccessModifiers {
    public function __construct($user_p, $user_fn, $user_ln, $user_id, $marks1, $marks2) {
        echo "hello1";
        $this->user_phone = $user_p;
        $this->user_fname = $user_fn;
        $this->user_lname = $user_ln;
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->marks1 = $marks1;
        $this->marks2 = $marks2;
        echo $this->marks1;
    }
    private $additional_marks = 10;

    public function calculate() {
        return $this->marks1 + $this->marks2 + $this->getAdditionalmarks();
    }
    public function getAdditionalmarks() {
        return $this->additional_marks;
    }
}

try {
    $test = new TestAccessModifiers("2345", "xyz", "vfd", "a0001", "99", "67"); /*invoking the class*/
    var_dump($test->calculate());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

you have defined a static method in your class, and have used the pseudo variable `$this` inside of the static method, which PHP does not allow. since static method is treated out of object context in PHP. you need to remove the static method to use `$this`

Answer (score 2):

Rename your *TestAccessModifiers* **function** to `__construct`.

```
public function __construct($user_p,$user_fn,$user_ln,$user_id,$marks1,$marks2) {
    echo "hello1";
    $this->user_phone = $user_p;
    $this->user_fname = $user_fn;
    $this->user_lname = $user_ln;
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->marks1 = $marks1;
    $this->marks2 = $marks2;
    echo $this->marks1;
}
```

Then, remove `static` from `calculate` function.

It should then works..

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

First: Which PHP version you have?
Second: Are you including the class file in the file that you are instancing?
Third: Your function "calculate" is static, then, you can't access to it from an instance and it have no way to read or write properties non-statics.

Try TestAccessModifiers::calculate(); and put in a simple return "Hello World"

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are we talking about?
First thing comes to mind: did you add it to autoload ? 
I would use the __constructor methode as initiator routine of the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function calculate() {
    return $this - > marks1 + $this - > marks2 + $this - > getAdditionalmarks();
}
```

You can't operate on `$this` from a static context. Make this method non-static, or adjust the other variables to be static, whichever suits your context.